# the rules in function overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

Look about this code (for example) :

```
#include <iostream>
void print(unsigned int value);
void print(float value);

int main() {
    print('a');
    print(0);
    print(3.14159);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the next error:

> 'print(char)' is ambiguous

What is really the problem here? I understood that more than one function appropiate to any call from the main (to print function). But what is really the rules in `function overloading` (How can I know what appropiate to what, between which types exists casts and etc.)

How can I know that more than one function appropiate to the call?  (more example: that not obvious how to understand that the two functions appropiate to the call)

```
#include <iostream>

void print(unsigned int value);
void print(int value);

int main() {
    print(2.5);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned int x = 5; print(x);` Solves the problem.

Comment: @Raindrop7  prefer to get a explanation than a private example. After you edited you comment: yes, I know that it's solves the problem but it's not explains the rules in function overloading.

Comment: Assume nothing about appropriate existing casts. If possible make sure your types match exactly, and if you can't do that then at least ensure that the type size and sign match. (e.g. `unsigned int` and `uint32_t` for a platform-specific implementation, or `char` and `int8_t` as a generic example)

Comment: A good reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: _How can I know that more than one function appropiate to the call?_ Compiling the code and seeing if compiler complains about it. When it complains, it is your responsability to teach it how to proceed

Comment: _"But what is really the rules in function overloading"_ You can't expect somebody to explain the full rules as an answer here, get a book or find a good tutorial on C++.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Can you recommend about a good book ?

Comment: See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: @Jor.Mal - The C++17 Standard has an entire chapter named "Overloading". It contains 33 pages! Not easy to create a quick summary. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you get because of missing version of the `print`:

```
print('a'); // calling print(int)
print(0);   // calling print(int) 
print(3.14159); // calling print(double) not float
```

As you can see `print(int)` and `print(double)` are missing also `print(char)` is missing you get those errors. When `print(char)` for example is not provided then the compiler search for `print(int)` thus it casts the passed in value to an integer.

To solve it you either add the version of overloaded `print` or cast explicitly the value passed in:

1- Overload the print:

```
void print(int value){ cout << "int: " <<  value << endl;}
void print(unsigned int value){ cout << "ui: " <<  value << endl;}
void print(float value){cout << "float: " << value << endl;}
void print(char c){ cout << "Char: " << c << endl;}
void print(double value){cout << "double: " << value << endl;}
```

2- Casting:

```
print((unsigned int)'a'); // or (float)
print((unsigned int)0);  // or (float)
print(3.14159f); // or (float)3.14159 or (unsigned int)3.14159
```

- Keep in mind that `print(3.14159);` is a call to `print(double);` not to `float` to do it for float: `print(3.14159f);`

Answer (score 5):

When you are working with function overload there is a lot of work that the compiler does behind the scenes to perform function overloading resolution. The details are to great to list here, however I can provide some links that may be of use and try to describe some of the more important parts.

- [cppreference : overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)
- [accu : overload resolution](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/268)
- [learn cpp : function overloading](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/76-function-overloading/)

---

> *There are 3 possible results:*
>
> - A match is found. The call is resolved to specific overload
> - No match found. The arguments can not be matched to any overload
> - An ambiguous match is found. Arguments matched more than one overload

---

> *The basic order of what the compiler will do is this:*
>
> - Find exact match based on parameter list
> - Tries to find a match through promotion
> - Tries to find a match through standard conversion
> - Tries to find a match through user-defined conversion

---

> So how is it determined if a call is ambiguous?

Since every overload has to have unique parameters and due to the fact that all standard conversions and all user-defined conversions are considered equal; if a function call matches more than one valid declaration-definition candidate through standard or user-defined conversion then the result will be ambiguous.

---

*From Your Example:*

```
void print( unsigned int value );
void print( float value );

print( 'a' );
print( 0 );
print( 3.14159 );
```

In the case of `print( 'a' );` C++ can not find an exact match. It will first try to promote `'a'` to an `int`, but there is no `print(int)` function that is declared-defined. It will then try to use standard conversion, it can convert `'a'` to both an `unsigned int` and a `floating point` value. And since all standard conversions are considered equal, this results in ambiguity.

---

To resolve this ambiguity you can either simply `declare-define` the needed versions of `print( type );` or you can explicitly cast the type to one of the provided overload parameter types.